# Struts-config.xml configuration mapping

Tags: java, struts

In struts-config I have action like this :

```
<action
      path="/action/basket"
      type="com.xxx.BasketAction"
      name="basketForm"
      scope="session"
      unknown="false"
      validate="false"
    >
      <forward
        name="displayItems"
        path="EshelfItems"
        redirect="false"
      />
      <forward
        name="displayItems-redirect"
        path="/action/basket.do?fn=display"
        redirect="true"
      />
      <forward
        name="displayBasket"
        path="/basket.jsp"
        redirect="false"
      />
    </action>
```

Where I can find the mapping for `/action/basket.do?fn=display` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The forward `displayItems-redirect` should be found somewhere in `com.xxx.BasketAction`...

Answer (score 0):

According to http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/works.html :

> In the framework configuration file(s), you associate paths with the
>   controller components of your application, known as Action classes
>   (i.e. "login" ==> LoginAction class). This tells the ActionServlet
>   that for the incoming request 'http://myhost/myapp/login.do' it should
>   invoke your controller component, LoginAction.
>
> Note the extension .do in this URL. The extension causes your
>   container (i.e. Tomcat) to call the ActionServlet, which sees the word
>   "login" as the thing you want to do. The configuration is referenced,
>   and your LoginAction is executed.

Check your `BasketAction` class where the `fn=display` request parameter is checked.
If you can't find the action class for a given mapping then debugging your 
[RequestProcessor's process](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/api/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.html#process%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method can be also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ya your question is not clear..
When you hit `/action/basket.do?fn=display` its going to use the following mapping in your struts config.

```
<action
      path="/action/basket"
```

And then it will execute

```
com.xxx.BasketAction
```

and in that class if you want you can read the param `fn=display` and then do a forward and that will work as mapped in `<forward>...</forward>` mapping of your struts config